# Making Ethereum transaction smart contarct input data in human readable

Tags: ethereum, solidity, bytecode, evm

In the following tx on testnet I'm looking to understand what the bytes value being passed as an input parameter actually is in a human readable form:

Tx: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x05da01fee2338a71956d8209b53364b1e9b9eaab3bf29e58f089438d7b06d7d1

Input data decoded using etherscan:
0

_palette

bytes
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

How can I convert this bytes value into a string or something human readable?

I've tried base64 decoders and i've had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a transaction human readable you need

- To have the ABI files of the compiled smart contract to know what is the function call in the transaction
- To have the source code of the smart contract and read it what it does when this function is called

[Then you can match the data field to the Solidity function selector and the function arguments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/106408/620).